# ¿Cómo colocar en una función el resultado de una derivada y poder evaluarla? En R

Tags: r, expression

Derivo la siguiente expresión matemática.

```
exp1<-expression(100/x)

D(exp1,"x")

# Lo que me resulta. 

-(100/x^2)
```

Lo que deseo es que este resultado se pueda introducir en una función. Para poder obtener los números que se generarán con ese resultado.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
f1<-function(x){
D(exp1,"x") 
}
```

Pero al tratar de ejecutar la función arroja el mismo resultado.

```
# Evaluando en el valor de 4.
f1(4)

# Arroja.
-(100/x^2)
```

Esto sucede porque el resultado de la derivada es de clase `call`.

Mi pregunta es cómo podría colocar en una función el resultado de la derivada y poder evaluarla. Es decir, en mi ejemplo, que al ejecutar resulte -6.25 (`-100/16`)

```
f1(4)
-6.25
# Que el resultado de esta operación sea -6.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1<-function(x){
  eval(D(exp1,"x")) 
}

f1(4)
[1] -6.25
```

No estoy exactamente seguro de por qué funciona, pero mi primera intuición fue poner un `eval()` explícito y funcionó. Creo que es lo que estabas buscando.

> PD: en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355547/expression-vs-call hay una conversación interesante sobre el tema, especialmente la diferencia entre `expression` y `call` en R. En ambos casos con `eval()` se logra que una llamada o expresión regrese un output evaluado y no la expresión o llamada propiamente dicha.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Quedó perfecto.